# Objective-C: Parsing String into an Array under Special Circumstances

Tags: objective-c, regex, parsing

I have a string:

> [{"id":1,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0},{"id":2,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0},{"id":3,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0}]

However, I would like to parse this string into an array such as:

> [{"id":1,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0},
>   {"id":2,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0},
>   {"id":3,"gameName":"arizona","cost":"0.5E1","email":"hi@gmail.com","requests":0}]

This array is delimited by the comma in between the curly braces: },{

I tride usign the command

```
NSArray *responseArray = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

but this separates the string into values at EVERY comma, which is not desirable.

Then I tried using regex:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{.*\\}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:response options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [response length])];
```

which found one match: starting at the first curly brace to the last curly brace.
I was wondering if anyone new how to solve this problem efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string seems to be valid JSON. Try a JSON parser: [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with H2CO3's suggestion to use a parser where possible.

But looking at your attempted regex, it looks like you just need to make it non-greedy, i.e.

```
@"\\{.*?\\}"
       ^
       |
       Add this question mark for non-greedy matching.
```

Of course, this will fail if you have deeper levels of (what I assume to be) nested arrays.  Go with the JSON parser!

Comment: I ended up using the JSON parser method, however, it's good to know how to make the regex non-greedy. Will come handy in the future. Thanks.